# Webcrypto PBKDF2-SHA1

Tags: javascript, cryptography, pbkdf2, hmacsha1, webcrypto

I am having an issue using PBKDF2 with Webcrypto. I would like to use PBKDF2 with the SHA-1 algorithm. Currently, I have,

```js
const ENCODING = "utf-8";
const HMACSHA1 = {name: "HMAC", "hash" : "SHA-1"};
const PBKDF2SHA1 = {name: "PBKDF2", "hash": "SHA-1"};

// str2binb takes a string and outputs an ArrayBuffer

async function pbkdf2_generate_key_from_string(string) { //  Working
  return crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    str2binb(string),
    PBKDF2SHA1,
    false,
    ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"],
  );
}

async function pbkdf2_derive_salted_key(key, salt, iterations) {  // Not working
  return crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {
      "name": "PBKDF2",
      "salt": salt,
      "iterations": iterations,
      "hash": "SHA-1",
      "length": 160
    },
    key,
    {
      "name": "HMAC"
      "hash": "SHA-1",
      "length": 160
    },
    true,
    [ "encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );
}
```

However I know I must be using it wrong, because it is a supported key derivation algorithm, and according to Mozilla's fantastic docs, under `derivedKeyAlgorithm` HMAC is supported as well as HMAC-SHA1. I also have it working with `AES-GCM` fairly straight forwardly.

The error message I am getting, when I try,

```js
salt = b64binb("QSXCR+Q6sek8bf92"); // ArrayBuffer
key = await pbkdf2_generate_key_from_string("pencil");
x = await pbkdf2_derive_salted_key(key, salt, 4096)
```

is `Uncaught DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.`

Note: I understand SHA1 is no longer recommended, this is for legacy support.

Note 2: It works when I replaced the above with,

```js
async function pbkdf2_derive_salted_key(key, data, salt, iterations) {  // Not working
  return crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {
      "name": "PBKDF2",
      salt: salt,
      "iterations": iterations,
      "hash": "SHA-1",
    },
    key,
    {
      "name": "AES-GCM",
      "length": 256
    },
    true,
    [ "encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `deriveKey`, the parameter `keyUsages` must be changed to `["sign", "verify"]`. Then the code works (since `b64binb`, `str2binb` were not posted, the following code uses appropriate substitutes):

```js
const b64binb = base64String => Uint8Array.from(atob(base64String), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
const str2binb = str => new TextEncoder().encode(str);
const buf2hex = buffer => Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');

async function pbkdf2_generate_key_from_string(string) { 
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        str2binb(string),
        {
            name: "PBKDF2",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"], 
    );
}

async function pbkdf2_derive_salted_key(key, salt, iterations) {  
    return crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: "PBKDF2",
            salt: salt,
            iterations: iterations,
            hash: {name: "SHA-1"}
        },
        key,
        {
            name: "HMAC",
            hash: "SHA-1",
            length: 160
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"] // <--------------------- Fix!
    );
}

async function test(){
    salt = b64binb("QSXCR+Q6sek8bf92"); // ArrayBuffer
    key = await pbkdf2_generate_key_from_string("pencil");
    x = await pbkdf2_derive_salted_key(key, salt, 4096)

    console.log(buf2hex(await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", x)));
}

test();
```

With this key, `window.crypto.subtle.sign` creates a signature using HMAC-SHA1.

**Update:**

Since in [*SubtleCrypto*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) the use of a key is generally specified, `["encrypt", "decrypt"]` must be applied as `keyUsages` parameter for AES-GCM and `["sign", "verify"]` for HMAC-SHA.

Why `["encrypt", "decrypt"]` for AES-GCM? AES-GCM is used for ***encrypting / decrypting*** messages: [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) describes a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) (allowing the encryption of a *single* block) and [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) the [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) (allowing the encryption of *more* than a single block). GCM provides confidentiality, authenticity and integrity.

And why `["sign", "verify"]` for HMAC-SHA? An HMAC is used for ***signing / verifying*** messages: Some modes of operation such as [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) only provide confidentiality. To *additionally* supply authenticity and integrity, the message can be signed with a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (e.g. an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) which is a specific type of MAC based on a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) e.g. one of the SHA family). The MAC is typically calculated from the ciphertext and not the plaintext ([*Encrypt-then-MAC*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202)). With regard to the SHA1 vulnerabilities, see for a comparison of HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-SHA256 [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26518) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15383).

Comment: Thank you! I just ran it, and it works. If you have the time to do another question lol, why does it change between `AES-GCM` and `HMAC-SHA1`?

Comment: @Justin - AES-GCM is for encryption/decryption, HMAC-SHA for signing/verifying, see the update section in my answer.

Comment: Appreciated! @Topaco